# Can someone explain to me how the containerization within snakemake works?

Tags: docker, containers, snakemake

I'm curious about the snakemake --use-singularity function works. Is snakemake running the analysis through a container using singularity exec or singularity pull? It seems to me that it is using kubernetes and docker and then runs the singularity through docker? What is the advantage of this over just using singularity on its own?

Essentially I've been trying to run some bioinformatics software through singularity on an HPC and have been running into issues such as the programs trying to write back to the image and singularity not giving permisison for that, was curious about how snakemake does it, but any other advice or resources for running bioinformatics programs through containers in an HPC is welcome.

Comment: Hi there, please provide some codes and expected outputs